# How do I pass paths with spaces to gem install on windows?

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems

The [documentation](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit) says:

> In this scenario you need to tell RubyGems where to find those headers and library files by using a command similar to gem install curb --platform=ruby -- --with-curl-lib="C:/curl/bin" --with-curl-include="C:/curl/include".

Is there a way to pass paths with spaces, like in the following command?

```
gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- --with-mysql-dir="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1"
```

Truth be told, I already know the answer:

```
gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-dir="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1"'
```

But I don't know the exact rules that govern it. It appears I can put several arguments in these single quotes:

```
gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-lib="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib" --with-mysql-include="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\include"'
```

And I don't know who exactly parses this command line.